tsconfig always suggest to import from src absolute path instead from relative
Currently when its one level down component that i need to access tsconfig suggests to import like so

(A ButtonChat JSX tag opened showing a suggested import from ../Buttons/ButtonChat)
But other components imports from src folder src/utils/sleep.util because i have
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "~src/*": ["src/*"]
        }

but how can i do the same for this ButtonChat?

I've updated your question so that the text in the image is text in the question. Please see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

"tsconfig always suggest to import from src absolute path instead from relative" ../Buttons/ButtonChat isn't an absolute path, it's a relative path. It's a different relative path than the one you've said you want (if I'm reading correctly that you want src/utils/sleep.util instead), but it's not absolute.
